# parsing decimals departed by whitespace in a text file in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing

My text file contains something like this:

```
1.56 10 998 24.87  // each separated by whitespace
```

I am trying to parse each decimal to float and store them in array-list.
I am thinking about using parseFloat method, but it's hard to do it because there are white spaces. What is the best way to parse my text file?

Comment: have a look at `java.util.Scanner`

Comment: Did you try Googling for the answer? What is wrong with String.Split()?

Answer (score 3):

Don't reinvent the wheel - let a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) do the heavy lifting for you:

```
List<Float> floats = new ArrayList<>();
try (Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"))) {
    while (s.hasNextFloat()) {
        floats.add(s.nextFloat());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your String with space and convert the results to Float :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("yourFile.txt"));
        String str = in.nextLine();//1.56 10 998 24.87
        String list[] = str.split(" ");
        List<Float> listFloat = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : list) {
            listFloat.add(Float.parseFloat(s));
        }
        System.out.println(listFloat);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NumberFormatException ex) {
        //Exception file not found or error of parsing 
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
[1.56, 10.0, 998.0, 24.87]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "1.56 10 998 24.87"
String[] splitString = myString.trim().split("\\s+");
```

You can then do your parsing on the individual strings within the String[]

To explain the code:

```
myString.trim().split("\\s+");
```

The \\s splits on whitespace.  The trim removes any whitespace before the splitting would start so that you don't get 'blank' Strings within your array.

Answer (score 0):

If u just want the string then this is fine

```
String myString = "1.56 10 998 24.87"
String[] splitString = myString.split("\\s+");
```

If u want the long value out of it

```
    String myString = "1.56 10 998 24.87";
    String[] splitString = myString.split("\\s+");
    List<Long> longList = Arrays.asList(splitString).stream().map(Long::parseLong).collect(Collectors.toList());
```